# perl Moose accessor madness - can't define only a reader or writer accessor!

Tags: perl, moose

So I'm just trying to do a very simple thing: define a custom reader accessor for a moose attribute.  So I try this:

```
has 'compiled_regex' => ( 
    isa => 'RegexpRef', 
    is => 'rw', 
    reader => 'get_compiled', 
);
```

but `get_compiled` never gets called, presumably because `compiled_regex` is read/write.  Ok, no problem.  I next try this:

```
 has 'compiled_regex' => ( 
     isa => 'RegexpRef', 
     writer => '_compile', 
     reader => 'get_compiled', 
 );
```

and that produces the following error:

> Can't locate object method "compiled_regex" via package "PrettyRegex" at ../lib/Pretty/Regexs.pm line 39.

which refers to this line which is in the _`compile` method:

```
$self->compiled_regex(qr/$self->regex/);
```

Now I haven't gotten much sleep in the past 3 days so maybe I'm confused, but it seems that even if this did work, it would create an infinite regress since I've defined the writer as `_compile` ... so what am I missing here?

tried Sinan answer but still getting:

```
Can't locate object method "compiled_regex" via package "PrettyRegex" at ../lib/Pretty/Regexs.pm line 41.
```

Comment: I don't know Moose enough to grok what the problem is, but someone please change the title of the post into a question.

Comment: I made the name of the reader `get_compiled_regex` when editing the script for some reason. That's why you are getting that message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unclear on what you're trying to do.  `reader` and `writer` are methods that Moose creates for you, not methods that you write and it calls.

I think you need to restate your question to explain the higher-level problem that you're trying to solve.  I expect there's a better way to do it than you've currently thought of, but we can't be sure without knowing what you're really trying to do.

If you're trying to get your custom method called when the attribute is read, just name the reader something else (like `_get_compiled_regex`), and name your method `compiled_regex`.  Or use a method modifier on the reader method.  (That's probably better, because then you won't forget to `die` if somebody passes a parameter to your reader method, trying to set the attribute.)

You also might want to have a trigger on some other attribute that clears this one.

Comment: here's the problem basically...I've defined a custom writer, say 'write_attr' on the attribute, say $self->my_attr.  Now the last line of write_attr is $self->my_attr($some_var).  This doesn't work for the reasons described in the question, but even if it did wouldn't it create an infinite regress since the last line of write_attr effectively calls write_attr?

Comment: @ennui: "the last line of write_attr..." indicates the problem: this is not a sub that you should be defining yourself. It is automatically generated with the 'writer' directive.

Comment: Why do you think you need a custom writer?  If the answer is along the lines of "because I want to run [some transformation] on the value passed in", you actually want a type constraint + coercion.

Comment: I too wonder how to write a customer reader. I'd like one as I have some logic in my writer so I need it to be calculated each time I read the attribute. I gave up in the end and just created a method that returned what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I keep guessing at what the actual question is, but I have a feeling the following corresponds to it:

```
package My::M;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

has 'compiled_regex' => (
    isa => 'RegexpRef',
    is  => 'ro',
    writer => '_set_compiled_regex',
);

sub compile {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($pat) = @_;
    $self->_set_compiled_regex(qr/$pat/);
    return;
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
use strict; use warnings;

my $m = My::M->new;
$m->compile( '^\W+\z' );

if ( '@#$%%$' =~ $m->compiled_regex ) {
    print "Hmph!\n";
}
```

Comment: @Ether sorry, the comment referred to Sinan first answer, not to the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Er? If your reader is called `get_compiled`, and your writer is called `_compile`, then you don't have a method named `compiled_regex`, and it should be obvious why a call to that nonexistent method would fail. You need to take several steps back and explain what you're trying to do, instead of what's going wrong with the way you've tried to do it.

Comment: you see this is why perl oo with moose is, er, weird. compiled_regex should be an attribute, not a method.....how that attribute is set should be, er, irrelevant. –